# Bacula storage daemon won't write to labeled volume

Tags: backup, storage, bacula

My Bacula configuration won't write to any labeled volume, as long as it's outside of `/tmp`. When the SD is configured to write to `/tmp` however, everything works flawlessly.

```
[herpderp@neuromediator2 home]$ ls -lah
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root     root       34 Feb 22 15:01 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 17 root     root     4.0K Feb 22 15:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 bacula   tape       20 Feb 22 15:03 bacula
drwx------. 14 herpderp herpderp 4.0K Feb 22 17:02 herpderp
```

I set the proper permissions to let Bacula write to a specific directory, yet without success.  The error message I get is below:

```
Jobs waiting to reserve a drive:
====

Terminated Jobs:
JobId  Level    Files      Bytes   Status   Finished        Name 
===================================================================
 2  Full          0         0   Cancel   22-Feb-16 16:16 BackupClient1
 7  Full          0         0   Cancel   23-Feb-16 10:19 BackupClient1
 1  Full        639    55.76 M  OK       23-Feb-16 10:20 Full_backup
 2  Full        697    60.58 M  OK       23-Feb-16 10:21 Full_backup
 3  Full          0         0   Cancel   23-Feb-16 11:48 Full_backup 
 ====

Device status:

Device "Storage" (/home/bacula/storage/) is not open.
 Device is BLOCKED waiting to create a volume for:
   Pool:        File
   Media type:  File
  ==
  ====

 Used Volume status:
 ====

 ====
```

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that the listing says

```
Device is BLOCKED waiting to create a volume for:
 Pool:        File
```

I was able to resolve my problem by labeling another volume using that pool.